# Besides commenting, does "#" have another other purpose in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I see this in programs where people will assign a line/multiple lines of code with "#". I thought this was strictly for commenting. How does this affect an overall program?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: By definition, comments are comments and thus are ignored at execution.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic "#G = -1.62" for a program that utilized the pull of gravity for final calculations. I don't see why the "#" needs to be there. Without it, the program doesn't work

Comment: @rainydayss it's in a string!

Comment: By *provide an example*, the intent is that you [edit] your question and provide an actual, usable example. Not a single line, totally out of context, buried in a comment.

Comment: `#G = -1.62` could be a comment telling you what the value of `G` is, or just giving an example value for `G`, if it's not obvious from the surrounding code.

Comment: It could also be commented-out code. Sometimes, when you get sick of debugging one bug, sometimes you disable some bits by turning them into comments. That lets you debug the next part of your code instead for a while. (Also, people living before the days of ubiquitous revision control tools used to sometimes leave commented-out code to show what the previous version used to do, and some really sloppy coders still do that.)

Answer (score 0):

For a short answer, it doesn't. The only thing the '#' is used for is making comments inside of your code, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

When you use tkinter, to make some specific shades you will have to put a hex in this `'#'`
like `'#ffffff'` or `'#00ff00'`

Answer (score 0):

This does not affect program, this code with an '#' can be an example of how to use this library or module, but it is being ignored by interpreter, so it does not do anything.